# Couldn't find Product without an ID build association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a problem with Ruby on Rails.When I try to create a line_items which is the association of product and cart ..siguiendo the book Agile web development with Rails.

Here's the code:

```
def create
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
#@line_item = LineItem.new(line_item_params)
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)

respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart,
      notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show',
      status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
      status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

if I uncomment the line:

```
line_item = LineItem.new(line_item_params)
```

and comment

```
#product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
#@line_item = @cart.add_product(product: product)
```

will it work?

I know in the `line_item_params` method which is the next

```
def line_item_params
  params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id, :cart_id)
end
```

allowable parameters defined to create the object.

Can someone help me build this?

Thanks

This is my form Code for the line_items, I can't copy the code because I blocked certain parts of code

---

```
<%= form_for(@line_item) do |f| %>
  <% if @line_item.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@line_item.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this line_item from  being saved:</h2>
 <ul>
  <% @line_item.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :product_id %><br>
<%= f.text_field :product_id %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :cart_id %><br>
<%= f.text_field :cart_id %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

---

This is the new method

```
 def new
  @line_item = LineItem.new
 end
```

This is the Product Model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :line_items
before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item

validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
validates :title, uniqueness: true
validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i,
    message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG Image.'
}

validates :title, length: {minimum: 10}

#para ultimo producto para cache
def self.latest
    Product.order(:updated_at).last
end

private
def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
    if line_items.empty?
        return true
    else
        errors.add(:base, 'Line Items present')
        return false
    end

end
end
```

This is the Cart Model

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

def add_product(product_id)
    current_item= line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if current_item
        current_item.quantity +=1
    else
        current_item= line_items.build(product_id: product_id)  
    end 
    current_item
end
end
```

This is the line_item Model

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :cart
 end
```

And this is my Module Cart

```
module CurrentCart
extend ActiveSupport::Concern
private
def set_cart 
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  @cart = Cart.create
  session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
end
end
```

Comment: Can you show me your form code

Comment: Hi Choco I send the code for my form, please help me ...Thanks

Comment: can you please add your `new` method and your models also

Comment: Hi Choco I send my new method and my models and module Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this and try:

```
def create
@cart = Cart.find(params[:line_item][:cart_id])
@product = Product.find(params[:line_item][:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: @product)

respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart,
      notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show',
      status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
      status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Choco,

I have one last question, what would be the correct way to use the creation of partnerships.

1) with the call to the method:
   params.require (: line_item) .permit (: product_id,: cart_id)

2) or as you raised me with array [: line_item] [: product_id]

Again many thanks Choco

Comment: @Zombie Please accept my answer if it would helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Choco , I did what you sent and run

```
@cart = Cart.find(params[:line_item][:cart_id])
@product = Product.find(params[:line_item][:product_id])
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: @product)
```

The arrays [:line_item][:cart_id].